# Drupal: change view argument

Tags: drupal, preprocessor, drupal-views, arguments, views2

I searched far and wide to find a working solution to this but couldn't find it.

What I want to do is change the argument that is passed to the view because I want for `pathauto` cleaned taxonomy terms to work as an argument. I have a code that transforms cleaned term back to a original one, but cannot make the view use it.

I saw some people changing it in `hook_preprocess_views_view(&$vars)` but in my case (Views 2.11) has a argument in `$vars` instanced so many times that it's not the way.

Can anyone please help me change this argument?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way but you could use views_embed_view() and set the arguments yourself

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas, either to add some custom php code to the view's argument's phpcode section that does something like this

```
$args[0] = 1;
return $args;
```

or try to use the function

```
hook_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  // modify $args value here
}
```

didn't test them so don't know which will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think `hook_views_pre_view` might help you do just that.